# Is there a way to move my imageview with the move of the slider thumb?

Tags: iphone, uislider

I want to move my imageview as user slide the thumb of UISlider and the image view should also have the value of the slider. Does any one have any idea about this?? Here's the code snippets:

```
   -(void)addSliderX:frame andminimumValue:(int)min andmaximumValue:(int)max andSliderValue:(int)value{
    CGRect frame1 = CGRectFromString(frame);
    statSlider = [[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:frame1];
    [statSlider setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenSlider.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:10.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    [statSlider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderBar_greenThumb.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [statSlider setMinimumValue:min];
    [statSlider setMaximumValue:max];
    statSlider.continuous = YES;
    [statSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [statSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //bubbleViewController = [[SFNDoorBubbleViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SFNDoorBubbleViewController"bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    //popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:bubbleViewController];
    //[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:bubbleViewController.view.frame.size];
    [self.view addSubview:statSlider]; 
}
-(void)valueChanged:(id)sender{


    UISlider *localSlider = (UISlider *)sender;
    bubble = [[UIView alloc]init];
    back = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderBar_handle_number.png"]];
    greenSliderValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.0f", [localSlider value]]];
    UILabel * val = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    dsp =[greenSliderValue floatValue];
    val.text = greenSliderValue;
    [bubbleViewController updateSliderValueTo:dsp];
    CGFloat sliderMax = localSlider.maximumValue;
    CGFloat sliderMin = localSlider.minimumValue;

    CGFloat sliderMaxMinDiff = sliderMax - sliderMin;
    CGFloat sliderValue = dsp;

    if(sliderMin < 0.0) {

        sliderValue = dsp-sliderMin;
        sliderMax = sliderMax - sliderMin;
        sliderMin = 0.0;
        sliderMaxMinDiff = sliderMax - sliderMin;
    }

    CGFloat xCoord = ((sliderValue-sliderMin)/sliderMaxMinDiff)*[localSlider frame].size.width-bubbleViewController.view.frame.size.width/2.0;

    CGFloat halfMax = (sliderMax+sliderMin)/2.0;

    if(sliderValue > halfMax) {

        sliderValue = (sliderValue - halfMax)+(sliderMin*1.0);
        sliderValue = sliderValue/halfMax;
        sliderValue = sliderValue*11.0;

        xCoord = xCoord - sliderValue;
    }

    else if(sliderValue <  halfMax) {

        sliderValue = (halfMax - sliderValue)+(sliderMin*1.0);
        sliderValue = sliderValue/halfMax;
        sliderValue = sliderValue*11.0;

        xCoord = xCoord + sliderValue;
    }
    [self.view addSubview:bubble];
    [bubble addSubview:back];
    [bubble addSubview:val];
    bubble.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord, 500, bubbleViewController.view.frame.size.width, bubbleViewController.view.frame.size.height);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime `changedValue:` gets called you create a new UIView, UIImageView and UILabel.
Instead of editing the old instances. That results that all old UIViews build a "path".

In your viewDidLoad you can create these three views and set on each the `.tag property`
**viewDidLoad**

```
UIView* bubble = [[UIView alloc]init];
UIImageView* back = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImageimageNamed:@"sliderBar_handle_number.png"]];
UILabel * val = [[UILabel alloc]init]
//other configurations ...
bubble.tag = 1;
back.tag = 2;
val.tag = 3; 
[self.view addSubview:bubble];
[bubble addSubview:back];
[bubble addSubview:val];
```

Now remove all the allocations, because we want to reuse the existing views. And we know their tags.
**(void)valueChanged:(id)sender**

```
UISlider *localSlider = (UISlider *)sender;
NSString* greenSliderValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.0f", [localSlider value]]];
UIView *bubble = (UIView*)[self.view.subviews viewWithTag:1];
UIImageView *back = (UIImageView*)[bubble.subviews viewWithTag:2];
UILabel *val = (UILabelw*)[bubble.subviews viewWithTag:3];
dsp =[greenSliderValue floatValue];
val.text = greenSliderValue;
[bubbleViewController updateSliderValueTo:dsp];
CGFloat sliderMax = localSlider.maximumValue;
CGFloat sliderMin = localSlider.minimumValue;

CGFloat sliderMaxMinDiff = sliderMax - sliderMin;
CGFloat sliderValue = dsp;

if(sliderMin < 0.0) {

sliderValue = dsp-sliderMin;
sliderMax = sliderMax - sliderMin;
sliderMin = 0.0;
sliderMaxMinDiff = sliderMax - sliderMin;
}

CGFloat xCoord = ((sliderValue-sliderMin)/sliderMaxMinDiff)*[localSlider frame].size.width-bubbleViewController.view.frame.size.width/2.0;

CGFloat halfMax = (sliderMax+sliderMin)/2.0;

if(sliderValue > halfMax) {

sliderValue = (sliderValue - halfMax)+(sliderMin*1.0);
sliderValue = sliderValue/halfMax;
sliderValue = sliderValue*11.0;

xCoord = xCoord - sliderValue;
}

else if(sliderValue <  halfMax) {

sliderValue = (halfMax - sliderValue)+(sliderMin*1.0);
sliderValue = sliderValue/halfMax;
sliderValue = sliderValue*11.0;

xCoord = xCoord + sliderValue;
}
bubble.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord, 500, bubbleViewController.view.frame.size.width, bubbleViewController.view.frame.size.height);
```

now you can use your existing instances

Comment: I did the same but the problem with that is now the its getting displayed throughout the path like the trail of same image which is not going invisible.

Comment: Please Post your Code than i can help  
i would say, that you recreate and add your UIImageViews everytime you changed the value

Comment: so all the above 6 lines of code should go into viewDidLoad ??

Comment: @Ashutosh no with the 3 on the bottom you overwrite you allocations in `valueChanged:`

Comment: it didn't work. Just want to make sure that i am not calling this valueChanged: from viewDidLoad. I am actually calling it form another function where i am using the slider (addSliderX:)

Comment: @Seega: i cannot add them to the view in viewDidLoad because then they will be visible from the very first step. There is step after which i am adding slider into my view and from there i am calling the valueChanged on slider change.

Comment: what about to a add the views then where you add your slider?!

Comment: Nope..Actually this view should appear once the user touches the thumb of the slider.

Comment: **viewdidload:** `"everyview".alpha = 0;`  **valuechanged:** `"everyviews".alpha = 1;`

Comment: just to let you know i am getting warnings on the above two lines....and that's where the code is breaking throwing SIGBART. please see the code above for warnings

Comment: do think about what i write? if i would write "jkfhlajdhblkjasdf" would you put it in your projekt????
you should set the alpha property for each of your threeviews....  
not copy "everyview"....

Comment: I do understand it, and i have put .alpha for each view and not everyview. The warning is in the valueChanged: where we are accessing viewWithtag:2 & 3. and the warning is NSArray may not respond to '-viewWithTag'

Comment: nice, if you give me the warning i can help you, im not at a mac at the moment so i cant tryout.  
but i think if you delete the ".subviews" it should work

Comment: Hey but is there a way to remove this bubble once we're done selecting the value of slider. Its not going away even after user is done selecting

Comment: use `initWithFrame:(CGFrame)` instead of only `init`